# What is the best timeout for online turn-based games?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, network-programming

What is the best time to set for the Socket as readtimeout and writetimeout for an online game?
Please tell me your recommendation and the reason.
Does it matter if it is a real time online game or a turn-based online game?
Thank you

Comment: how long should you wait for a message before you decide the player's computer crashed?

Comment: @user253751It is my question. What is a standard time ?

Comment: if there was a standard, it wouldn't ask you. Somewhere between 30 seconds and 600 seconds.